# Riemannian metric on Lie Groups and $S^n$

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

I am studying Riemannian Geometry by myself and I am following the textbook *Riemannian Geometry* by *Manfredo Perdigao do Carmo*.

The Riemannian metric on a Lie group G is given by defining it on the tangent space of the neutral element *e* and it is given by:

$$\langle u,v\rangle_x = \langle (dL_{x^{-1}})_x(u),(dL_{x^{-1}})_x(v)\rangle_e\ ,\text{ where } x \in G, u,v \in T_xG.$$

I have verified all the properties of a Riemannian metric except for the smoothness.

Since a Riemannian metric is a 2-tensor and not a differential form, I am not sure how to understand it's pullback (by $L_{x^{-1}})$. Can somebody explain how the metric is varying smoothly due to the smoothness of $L_{x^{-1}}$. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I also want to know how to find an explicit formula for a Riemannian metric on $S^n$ which is induced by the pullback of the inclusion map from $\Bbb R^n$ to $S^n$.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1326735/proving-smoothness-of-left-invariant-metric-on-a-lie-group. Also, this question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332811/how-to-formalize-the-fact-that-g-h-mapsto-dl-g-h-is-smooth-where-g-h-in?noredirect=1&lq=1) seems relevant as well.